# How to create .htaccess redirect for directories but different for subdirectories?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a site that uses a URL structure like this:

- site.com/companyname  - general page for company
- site.com/companyname/login  - login for company admins

The site is switching to a different domain/structure and we need to redirect like this

- site.com/companyname > newsite.com/companyname
- site.com/companyname/login > newsite.com/login

I'm having trouble getting this to work since the first companyname redirect is happening for both URLs I can target the '/login'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work with the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !login
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ https://newsite.com/$1 

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} login
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ https://newsite.com/login
```